# Can't modify /System/Library/Frameworks

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo, macos-sierra, mv

I'm trying to install GLEW, based on [this link](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2010/fall/cs381/docs/macGLEW_install.html). But, when I tried to modify `/System/Library/Frameworks/`, even with sudo, I'm met with permission denied.

```
Enrico@~/D/g/M/b/Release sudo mv GLEW.framework/ /System/Library/Frameworks/
mv: rename GLEW.framework/ to /System/Library/Frameworks/GLEW.framework/: Operation not permitted
```

Here's what the permissions look like:

```
Enrico@/S/Library ls -l | grep Frameworks
drwxr-xr-x  139 root  wheel   4726 Sep  4 12:12 Frameworks
```

Also, when I inspect the folder in Finder with "Get info", it says at the bottom, "You can only read". Even though I can unlock the golden lock on the bottom right.

Just to be clear, this question is not about GLEW. It's more about why I can't modify that folder, even with root user enabled.

I'm on macOS Sierra.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most of /System is protected by [system integrity protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really). In general, locally-installed frameworks should go in /Library/Frameworks, not under /System.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thanks! So, if I disable SIP, I should be able to modify /System/Library/Frameworks?

Comment: It'd really be better to put it under /Library/Frameworks instead. Turning off SIP for something like this is going out of your way to do it wrong.

Comment: Yea, I completely understand that. I will put it under /library/frameworks. Was just curious if turning off SIP would allow me to write to this folder. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it